# C: handling case...else

Tags: c, switch-statement

What is the correct way to put an `else` clause in a `switch` statement? For example, instead of:

```
switch (input) {
    case (1):
        printf("yes!");
        break
    case (0):
        printf("no!");
        break;
   default:
        printf("invalid!");
}
```

To do something along the lines of (if possible):

```
switch (input) {
    case (1):
        printf("yes!");
    case (0):
        printf("no!");
   else:
        printf("invalid!");
}
```

I'm simply asking if there is a short-cut to not have to add a `break` after every case statement to act as-if it were the `else` part of an `if` statement.

Comment: Develop your own programming language. C won't have `else` in `switch` statement unless the `else` is for `if` inside the `switch` statement.

Comment: Surely you'd put `break` in every case anyway...?

Comment: @EugeneSh. sure, I'm wondering if there's a way without break.

Comment: The `default:` case is used for anything that does match another `case`. Re the edits: there is no use "guessing" how the C syntax works.

Comment: `break` and `default` are integral part of `swich/case` syntax. If you don't want use them, use `if/else`.

Comment: Not every case requires `break` though, some of them might be "fall-through" depending on the required logic.

Comment: Your first example using `break` is correct and idiomatic (except the `'` should all be `"`, and people usually omit the parentheses and write `case 0:`).  There's no reasonable alternative, short of macro hackery that may save you typing but will confuse readers.  I agree that always having the `break` is tedious (and leaving it out will change the behavior of the code, due to fall through), but it's just an annoyance that you get used to.

Comment: There's no standard shortcut (& I'm not aware of a nonstandard one either). However if you start each case label including default with `break;` as in `break;case 42:`, `break;default:;`, then you get a switch where it's quickly obvious none of the branches has fallthrough while at the same time you're saved from having to worry about `break;`ing those branches at their end.

Comment: "There's no reasonable alternative, short of macro hackery that may save you typing but will confuse readers." Imagine my frustration the first time I tried to read the source for the Bourne shell

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is using default. Also ,you don't have to use break for non-default cases, only if you don't want execution to fall into the next case.